# My accuracy for the ANN is not coming perfect

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
crop: object = CropData(path= '')    
crop.dataset: pd.DataFrame = CropAnalysis.rename_columns(dataset= 
crop.dataset)
crop.dataset.head()


data_charaterictics: Generator = 
CropAnalysis.data_characteristics(dataset= crop.dataset)
while True:
try:
    print('-'*100)
    print(data_charaterictics.__next__())
except StopIteration: break


unique_values: Generator = 
CropAnalysis.data_unique_values(dataset= crop.dataset)
while True:
try:
    print('-'*100)
    print(unique_values.__next__())
except StopIteration: break

target_classification: Generator = 
CropAnalysis.target_classification_count(dataset= crop.dataset, 
target= 'crop') 
while True:
try:
    print('-'*100)
    print(target_classification.__next__())
except StopIteration: break

crop.dataset.keys()

numeric_histoplots: Generator = 
CropAnalysis.histograms_numeric_features(dataset= crop.dataset,
                                                                     
numeric_features= [
                                                                         
'Nitrogen', 'Phosphorus',
                                                                         
'Potassium', 'Temp','hum', 'PH','Rain'
                                                                        
]    )
while True:
try: numeric_histoplots.__next__()
except AttributeError: break

crop.dataset: pd.DataFrame = 
CropPreprocess.change_object_to_str(dataset= crop.dataset, cols= 
['crop'])
crop.dataset: pd.DataFrame = 
CropPreprocess.encode_features(dataset= crop.dataset)
crop.dataset

X, y = crop.dataset.drop('crop', axis= 1), crop.dataset['crop']
from sklearn import preprocessing
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalizer()
normalized_train_X = normalizer.fit_transform(X_train)
normalized_train_X

from tensorflow.keras import utils
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
one_hot_y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
one_hot_y_test = to_categorical(y_test)


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=tts(X,y,test_size=0.2)

 from tensorflow import keras

 from tensorflow.keras import layers , Sequential
```

`    from keras.layers import Dense

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# Neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 
'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 25, epochs = 100)
```

The value of the accuracy and loss is way to small such as 0.04 which is not the same with machine learning algorithms, the size of the data is also big like 2200*8 which is not small. Help me find out what is the problem with the data
The dataset is provided in here https://www.kaggle.com/atharvaingle/crop-recommendation-dataset

Comment: Hey Tanya, what's seems to be happening is that your modeling is not converging in train. If the model doesn't adapt to your data this could be trash (garbage in garbage out principle) or your model architecture isn't good enough (this might seem to be the case). Try another neural network architecture because I don't think theone you have is gonna work. Try googling some of them, or at least increase nodes in the dense layer and change activaction function of your layers (except from the last layer ). I'm not an expert in keras framework but this seems to be many of your problems

Comment: Using softmax with only one neuron makes no sense, as it produces a constant value of 1.0

Comment: @Tom could you help me more with it , I m not able to understand it. If possible could you please alter the code. I have done all of what I could do on my end and still not able to find out the correct one. Please help me with this

Comment: @Dr Snoopy The error I m getting is ValueError: Unknown loss function: crossentropy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument.. Help me sort out

Comment: The loss is not called like that, there is binary_crossentropy or categorical_crossentropy.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy on doing so the accuracy turns out to be 0.0413 . I m dealing with Classification models so no other type of loss can be used. what shall i do next so that the accuracy increases than this?

Comment: No, that is not how Stack Overflow works, you can edit your question to add additional information. There is no need for email. Did you see my comment about the use of softmax with a single neuron?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy can you provide me with the change. I m new to deep learning. Not able to figure out wat you are trying to say. Just provide me the change pls. It would really help. I have even made the changes

Comment: You should set the number of neurons in the last layer equal to the number of classes (and you did not provide that information).

Comment: See this , https://www.kaggle.com/aryannath/crop-recommendation-with-xgboost ; for problems with structured data you should be aware that models like xgbost randomforsest (and other ensemble tree based models) often outperform deep learning models. If you wanna improve your model change the NN arch or I highly reccomed you to deep dive into xgboost or somthinglikethat

Comment: @Tom the problem that I m facing is that I have to do it with ANN as my assignment. I have ben doing this from the past 20 days without any scope of improvement. This is my last chance of doing it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more neurons to your output layer. Currently you are predicting whether to use a single crop or not. But in the Kaggle dataset the labels are actually 22 different crops and you want to decide which crop is most suitable to the soil at hand.
So you need 22 neurons in your output layer, i.e. change your last layer to

```
model.add(Dense(22, activation='softmax'))
```

The resulting prediction will indicate which crop is most suitable for the soil.

Make sure that `y_train,y_test`are one hot vectors for this. If they're not yet, you can convert them f.e. by using `one_hot_y_train = to_categorical(y_train)`

Comment: I m still getting this error @yuki ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 22) are incompatible

Comment: from tensorflow.keras import utils
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical                                            one_hot_y_train = to_categorical(y_train)                                                                                               one_hot_y_test = to_categorical(y_test)                                                                                                       from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=tts(X,y,test_size=0.2)

Comment: @TanyaSaraswat People have been helping you, but its not easy with partial information, so please stop begging for help, just provide additional information. From this error, did  you change the number of neurons in the last layer to 22 AND one-hot encoded your labels? Also which loss are you using now?

Comment: I have changed it in the last layer, also hot encoded the labels. The loss I m using is categorical_crossentropy. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: @TanyaSaraswat Update your question with your latest code then.

Comment: The error message ```Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 22)``` looks as if you haven't adjusted the number of neurons in the last layer or as if you are not passing the correct one-hot-encoded targets to your model. But I cannot know this without seeing the updated code

Comment: @yuki I have updated the code, please have a look.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Updated

Comment: @TanyaSaraswat Your one-hot encoded labels are in another variable ( one_hot_y_train ), not in y_train, same for test labels.